# Admin access along with django-facebook

Tags: django, django-facebook

I am new to setting up django-facebook. I tried to set it up as per the docs/tutorial. Is there a way to setup a separate way for admin account access? When I run syncdb, it does not ask me to setup admin/superuser when I set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` to my custom user.

Comment: Did you try `python manage.py createsuperuser`?

Comment: Nope, that does not work. For e.g., if I set AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'django_facebook.FacebookCustomUser' (using example from docs), it gives me following error "$ python manage.py createsuperuser
Username: admin
DatabaseError: no such table: django_facebook_facebookcustomuser"

Comment: Looks like an issue with South setup. Let me dig further

Comment: Found the issue that django-facebook was under South. There were two *_initial.py files in my migrations directory of django-facebook. This caused python manage.py migrate to fail with an error 'Table already exists'. Consequently, the db tables for django-facebook were not created. Fixed it and works fine now. Thanks for your help though ! :)